# Android C2DM Registration fails INVALID_PARAMETERS

Tags: java, android, parameters, android-c2dm

Hi I have done all things right, got all permissions right, signed_up my application. I even get a response from google when I call the com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER. Is there something wrong with the google servers? I only got a mail From: noreply@google.com, Subject:     AC2DM invitation.

- Do I need another activation mail? I signed up the form one day ago...
- Is there anyway to test the google c2dm side?

  ```
  Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
  registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
  registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", "mail@gmail.com");
  this.startService(registrationIntent);
  ```

Comment: Make sure that the sender email is the email used to sign up with C2DM and make sure that you do NOT have that same email registered on your phone/emulator

Comment: Also post your stack trace so it is clear where the error is. It could be a problem with your c2dm receiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your 2 questions:

- Do I need another activation mail? I signed up the form one day ago...

  You do not need another activation mail. If you read your email carefully, it doesn't guarantee that it will work within a day (took mine almost 2 full days to work).

  Per the email: *... and you should be able to
  start using it to send messages to Android 2.2 devices within the next
  day or so.*
- Is there anyway to test the google c2dm side?

  Trying to register your application is the best way to test it. If you receive a response in your receiver's `onReceive` function, it means that Google's server-side is working fine.

Comment: Thank you I'll have to wait then ;)

Comment: EDIT: It's working now, I resubmitted a sign up form, and restarted the simulator! When someone got the same fault, be patient and check the "sender" email address is correct!